# Use Spring data elasticsearch in AWS Lambda

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, spring-data-elasticsearch

Spring data elasticsearch provides annotations so I don't need to create the index mapping json manually, it also takes care of updating the indexes automatically.

I want to take advantage of all those, but my environment is serverless (AWS Lambda), so cold start up time is a concern.

I'm wondering if there are alternatives to Spring data elasticsearch that do similar things OR if I can use Spring data elasticsearch without making my lambda a Springboot/spring application?

I tried searching existing questions but didn't yield result.

Thanks in advance.